# What is Ans in javascript?

Tags: javascript

One time, I came across this code.

```
var Ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?");
if(Ans==true) {
    return true;
else {
    return false;
}
```

And I was really confused. Ans probably stands for answer, but what does it do?

Comment: It is just a normal variable.

Comment: check [Javascript MDN: confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)

Comment: It says `var Ans`. Although the convention is to use lowercase for variables, `var` is used to declare a variable. `Ans` is just that.

Answer (score 1):

`Ans` is just a variable in this case. The `confirm` function returns true or false depending on whether the user clicked yes or no.

So, the code is just saying "If the user answered yes, return true".

A much simpler way to write the code is:

```
return confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?");
```

Comment: Oh. Stupid me. I should of thought that it was just a normal variable. Ugh.

Comment: I thought it was like a special variable that means something important. Now I get why this has 5 downvotes.  :(